# Codeigniter unchecked checkbox value = blank?

Tags: php, codeigniter, filter, checkbox

I have this database where I have to capture a lot of yes/no questions, and the prefered method for the users is checkboxes. Everything is working as it should, except when it comes to retreive and show the values. Unchecked boxes return values of "0"

Is there anyway to either ignore and not display "0" in the reports OR change the default value from "0" to blank"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is nothing to do with CodeIgniter. :)
How about this?

```
if($_POST['checkbox']==0) 
    $_POST['checkbox'] = '';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
result = $this->input->post('checkbox',TRUE)==null ? 0 : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is returning 0 because that is false and that's what check boxes returned when not checked. Just add an if in your CI processing method that returns whatever value you want if the checkbox value==0.

Edit: Just to clarify, this doesn't have anything to do with your CI. What I mean by it is returning 0 is that that is what the form itself is returning - that the behavior of a checkbox. To change the value will take a quick check in your CI code to change the 0 to a value you want. I assume you are accessing the value somewhere to create your email.

Answer (score 1):

since the the **checkbox** returning null value while unchecked, you won't get a value while posting. Here is a simple quick solution for returning **unchecked value from checkbox**,

```
<input type="hidden" name="cbox" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="1" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but I found it helpful to make the hidden input with a value of -1 as 0 and FALSE caused problems for me after casting as an INT.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ! $_POST['checkbox']) $_POST['checkbox'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox is not checked, no data is sent for it.  (If it is checked, the value attribute is sent).  Attempting to read `$_POST['checkbox']` will cause a PHP error (unless you use  `empty()` or `isset()`, which are special language constructs).

`this->input->post('checkbox')` will return `FALSE` if the checkbox data is not set, i.e. if it was not checked.  There's no way to change that value, I'm afraid.  If you want a different value, you will need to manually compare FALSE and use a different value.

Finally, when you submit FALSE to the database using CodeIgniter's DB access API, it is converted to '0'.  This would work well for a boolean column in the database.  When you read out a boolean column, you'll get whatever your database's preferred code for TRUE is, regardless of what you submitted originally.  (With the possible exception of sqlite, which is weakly-typed, a bit like PHP is).